# Problem With Samba Share between Ubuntu 18.04 & Kali Linux

Tags: 18.04, samba, kali

I have a problem With Samba Share between Ubuntu 18.04 & Kali Linux 2019.4

Kali Linux IP: 192.168.0.26

See the logs of smbclient

```
        vitor@ubuntu18:~$ smbclient -L 192.168.0.26 -U root --workgroup=WORKGROUP
        WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
        Enter WORKGROUP\root's password: 

            Sharename       Type      Comment
            ---------       ----      -------
            print$          Disk      Printer Drivers
            kali            Disk      
            IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (Samba 4.11.1-Debian)
            root            Disk      Home Directories
        SMB1 disabled -- no workgroup available
```

And the smb.conf of Kali Linux

```
        root@kali:/etc/samba# cat smb.conf 
        #
        # Sample configuration file for the Samba suite for Debian GNU/Linux.
        #
        #
        # This is the main Samba configuration file. You should read the
        # smb.conf(5) manual page in order to understand the options listed
        # here. Samba has a huge number of configurable options most of which 
        # are not shown in this example
        #
        # Some options that are often worth tuning have been included as
        # commented-out examples in this file.
        #  - When such options are commented with ";", the proposed setting
        #    differs from the default Samba behaviour
        #  - When commented with "#", the proposed setting is the default
        #    behaviour of Samba but the option is considered important
        #    enough to be mentioned here
        #
        # NOTE: Whenever you modify this file you should run the command
        # "testparm" to check that you have not made any basic syntactic 
        # errors. 

        #======================= Global Settings =======================

        [global]

        ## Browsing/Identification ###

        # Change this to the workgroup/NT-domain name your Samba server will part of
           workgroup = WORKGROUP

        #### Networking ####

        # The specific set of interfaces / networks to bind to
        # This can be either the interface name or an IP address/netmask;
        # interface names are normally preferred
        #interfaces = 192.168.0.0/24 eth0

        # Only bind to the named interfaces and/or networks; you must use the
        # 'interfaces' option above to use this.
        # It is recommended that you enable this feature if your Samba machine is
        # not protected by a firewall or is a firewall itself.  However, this
        # option cannot handle dynamic or non-broadcast interfaces correctly.
        ;   bind interfaces only = yes

        client min protocol = smb2
        client max protocol = smb3

        #### Debugging/Accounting ####

        # This tells Samba to use a separate log file for each machine
        # that connects
           log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m

        # Cap the size of the individual log files (in KiB).
           max log size = 1000

        # We want Samba to only log to /var/log/samba/log.{smbd,nmbd}.
        # Append syslog@1 if you want important messages to be sent to syslog too.
           logging = file

        # Do something sensible when Samba crashes: mail the admin a backtrace
           panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d


        ####### Authentication #######

        # Server role. Defines in which mode Samba will operate. Possible
        # values are "standalone server", "member server", "classic primary
        # domain controller", "classic backup domain controller", "active
        # directory domain controller". 
        #
        # Most people will want "standalone server" or "member server".
        # Running as "active directory domain controller" will require first
        # running "samba-tool domain provision" to wipe databases and create a
        # new domain.
           server role = standalone server

           obey pam restrictions = yes

        # This boolean parameter controls whether Samba attempts to sync the Unix
        # password with the SMB password when the encrypted SMB password in the
        # passdb is changed.
           unix password sync = yes

        # For Unix password sync to work on a Debian GNU/Linux system, the following
        # parameters must be set (thanks to Ian Kahan <<kahan@informatik.tu-muenchen.de> for
        # sending the correct chat script for the passwd program in Debian Sarge).
           passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
           passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .

        # This boolean controls whether PAM will be used for password changes
        # when requested by an SMB client instead of the program listed in
        # 'passwd program'. The default is 'no'.
           pam password change = yes

        # This option controls how unsuccessful authentication attempts are mapped
        # to anonymous connections
           map to guest = bad user

        ########## Domains ###########

        #
        # The following settings only takes effect if 'server role = primary
        # classic domain controller', 'server role = backup domain controller'
        # or 'domain logons' is set 
        #

        # It specifies the location of the user's
        # profile directory from the client point of view) The following
        # required a [profiles] share to be setup on the samba server (see
        # below)
        ;   logon path = \\%N\profiles\%U
        # Another common choice is storing the profile in the user's home directory
        # (this is Samba's default)
        #   logon path = \\%N\%U\profile

        # The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
        # It specifies the location of a user's home directory (from the client
        # point of view)
        ;   logon drive = H:
        #   logon home = \\%N\%U

        # The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
        # It specifies the script to run during logon. The script must be stored
        # in the [netlogon] share
        # NOTE: Must be store in 'DOS' file format convention
        ;   logon script = logon.cmd

        # This allows Unix users to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
        # RPC pipe.  The example command creates a user account with a disabled Unix
        # password; please adapt to your needs
        ; add user script = /usr/sbin/adduser --quiet --disabled-password --gecos "" %u

        # This allows machine accounts to be created on the domain controller via the 
        # SAMR RPC pipe.  
        # The following assumes a "machines" group exists on the system
        ; add machine script  = /usr/sbin/useradd -g machines -c "%u machine account" -d /var/lib/samba -s /bin/false %u

        # This allows Unix groups to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
        # RPC pipe.  
        ; add group script = /usr/sbin/addgroup --force-badname %g

        ############ Misc ############

        # Using the following line enables you to customise your configuration
        # on a per machine basis. The %m gets replaced with the netbios name
        # of the machine that is connecting
        ;   include = /home/samba/etc/smb.conf.%m

        # Some defaults for winbind (make sure you're not using the ranges
        # for something else.)
        ;   idmap config * :              backend = tdb
        ;   idmap config * :              range   = 3000-7999
        ;   idmap config YOURDOMAINHERE : backend = tdb
        ;   idmap config YOURDOMAINHERE : range   = 100000-999999
        ;   template shell = /bin/bash

        # Setup usershare options to enable non-root users to share folders
        # with the net usershare command.

        # Maximum number of usershare. 0 means that usershare is disabled.
        #   usershare max shares = 100

        # Allow users who've been granted usershare privileges to create
        # public shares, not just authenticated ones
           usershare allow guests = yes

        #======================= Share Definitions =======================

        [homes]
           comment = Home Directories
           browseable = no

        # By default, the home directories are exported read-only. Change the
        # next parameter to 'no' if you want to be able to write to them.
           read only = yes

        # File creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
        # create files with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
           create mask = 0700

        # Directory creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
        # create dirs. with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
           directory mask = 0700

        # By default, \\server\username shares can be connected to by anyone
        # with access to the samba server.
        # The following parameter makes sure that only "username" can connect
        # to \\server\username
        # This might need tweaking when using external authentication schemes
           valid users = %S

        # Un-comment the following and create the netlogon directory for Domain Logons
        # (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
        ;[netlogon]
        ;   comment = Network Logon Service
        ;   path = /home/samba/netlogon
        ;   guest ok = yes
        ;   read only = yes

        # Un-comment the following and create the profiles directory to store
        # users profiles (see the "logon path" option above)
        # (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
        # The path below should be writable by all users so that their
        # profile directory may be created the first time they log on
        ;[profiles]
        ;   comment = Users profiles
        ;   path = /home/samba/profiles
        ;   guest ok = no
        ;   browseable = no
        ;   create mask = 0600
        ;   directory mask = 0700

        [printers]
           comment = All Printers
           browseable = no
           path = /var/spool/samba
           printable = yes
           guest ok = no
           read only = yes
           create mask = 0700

        # Windows clients look for this share name as a source of downloadable
        # printer drivers
        [print$]
           comment = Printer Drivers
           path = /var/lib/samba/printers
           browseable = yes
           read only = yes
           guest ok = no
        # Uncomment to allow remote administration of Windows print drivers.
        # You may need to replace 'lpadmin' with the name of the group your
        # admin users are members of.
        # Please note that you also need to set appropriate Unix permissions
        # to the drivers directory for these users to have write rights in it
        ;   write list = root, @lpadmin

        [kali]
        path = /root/
        browseable = yes
        read only = no
        guest ok = no
        create mask = 0700
        #valid users = root
```

And the smb.conf of Ubuntu 18.04:

```
        #
        # Sample configuration file for the Samba suite for Debian GNU/Linux.
        #
        #
        # This is the main Samba configuration file. You should read the
        # smb.conf(5) manual page in order to understand the options listed
        # here. Samba has a huge number of configurable options most of which 
        # are not shown in this example
        #
        # Some options that are often worth tuning have been included as
        # commented-out examples in this file.
        #  - When such options are commented with ";", the proposed setting
        #    differs from the default Samba behaviour
        #  - When commented with "#", the proposed setting is the default
        #    behaviour of Samba but the option is considered important
        #    enough to be mentioned here
        #
        # NOTE: Whenever you modify this file you should run the command
        # "testparm" to check that you have not made any basic syntactic 
        # errors. 

        #======================= Global Settings =======================

        [global]

        ## Browsing/Identification ###

        # Change this to the workgroup/NT-domain name your Samba server will part of
           workgroup = WORKGROUP

        # server string is the equivalent of the NT Description field
            server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)

        # Windows Internet Name Serving Support Section:
        # WINS Support - Tells the NMBD component of Samba to enable its WINS Server
        #   wins support = no

        # WINS Server - Tells the NMBD components of Samba to be a WINS Client
        # Note: Samba can be either a WINS Server, or a WINS Client, but NOT both
        ;   wins server = w.x.y.z

        # This will prevent nmbd to search for NetBIOS names through DNS.
           dns proxy = no

        client min protocol = smb2

        #client min protocol = smb2
        #client max protocol = smb3

        #unix extensions = No

        #### Networking ####

        # The specific set of interfaces / networks to bind to
        # This can be either the interface name or an IP address/netmask;
        # interface names are normally preferred
        ;   interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 eth0

        # Only bind to the named interfaces and/or networks; you must use the
        # 'interfaces' option above to use this.
        # It is recommended that you enable this feature if your Samba machine is
        # not protected by a firewall or is a firewall itself.  However, this
        # option cannot handle dynamic or non-broadcast interfaces correctly.
        ;   bind interfaces only = yes



        #### Debugging/Accounting ####

        # This tells Samba to use a separate log file for each machine
        # that connects
           log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m

        # Cap the size of the individual log files (in KiB).
           max log size = 1000

        # If you want Samba to only log through syslog then set the following
        # parameter to 'yes'.
        #   syslog only = no

        # We want Samba to log a minimum amount of information to syslog. Everything
        # should go to /var/log/samba/log.{smbd,nmbd} instead. If you want to log
        # through syslog you should set the following parameter to something higher.
           syslog = 0

        # Do something sensible when Samba crashes: mail the admin a backtrace
           panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d


        ####### Authentication #######

        # Server role. Defines in which mode Samba will operate. Possible
        # values are "standalone server", "member server", "classic primary
        # domain controller", "classic backup domain controller", "active
        # directory domain controller". 
        #
        # Most people will want "standalone sever" or "member server".
        # Running as "active directory domain controller" will require first
        # running "samba-tool domain provision" to wipe databases and create a
        # new domain.
           server role = standalone server

        # If you are using encrypted passwords, Samba will need to know what
        # password database type you are using.  
           passdb backend = tdbsam

           obey pam restrictions = yes

        # This boolean parameter controls whether Samba attempts to sync the Unix
        # password with the SMB password when the encrypted SMB password in the
        # passdb is changed.
           unix password sync = yes

        # For Unix password sync to work on a Debian GNU/Linux system, the following
        # parameters must be set (thanks to Ian Kahan <<kahan@informatik.tu-muenchen.de> for
        # sending the correct chat script for the passwd program in Debian Sarge).
           passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
           passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .

        # This boolean controls whether PAM will be used for password changes
        # when requested by an SMB client instead of the program listed in
        # 'passwd program'. The default is 'no'.
           pam password change = yes

        # This option controls how unsuccessful authentication attempts are mapped
        # to anonymous connections
           map to guest = bad user

        ########## Domains ###########

        #
        # The following settings only takes effect if 'server role = primary
        # classic domain controller', 'server role = backup domain controller'
        # or 'domain logons' is set 
        #

        # It specifies the location of the user's
        # profile directory from the client point of view) The following
        # required a [profiles] share to be setup on the samba server (see
        # below)
        ;   logon path = \\%N\profiles\%U
        # Another common choice is storing the profile in the user's home directory
        # (this is Samba's default)
        #   logon path = \\%N\%U\profile

        # The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
        # It specifies the location of a user's home directory (from the client
        # point of view)
        ;   logon drive = H:
        #   logon home = \\%N\%U

        # The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
        # It specifies the script to run during logon. The script must be stored
        # in the [netlogon] share
        # NOTE: Must be store in 'DOS' file format convention
        ;   logon script = logon.cmd

        # This allows Unix users to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
        # RPC pipe.  The example command creates a user account with a disabled Unix
        # password; please adapt to your needs
        ; add user script = /usr/sbin/adduser --quiet --disabled-password --gecos "" %u

        # This allows machine accounts to be created on the domain controller via the 
        # SAMR RPC pipe.  
        # The following assumes a "machines" group exists on the system
        ; add machine script  = /usr/sbin/useradd -g machines -c "%u machine account" -d /var/lib/samba -s /bin/false %u

        # This allows Unix groups to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
        # RPC pipe.  
        ; add group script = /usr/sbin/addgroup --force-badname %g

        ############ Misc ############

        # Using the following line enables you to customise your configuration
        # on a per machine basis. The %m gets replaced with the netbios name
        # of the machine that is connecting
        ;   include = /home/samba/etc/smb.conf.%m

        # Some defaults for winbind (make sure you're not using the ranges
        # for something else.)
        ;   idmap uid = 10000-20000
        ;   idmap gid = 10000-20000
        ;   template shell = /bin/bash

        # Setup usershare options to enable non-root users to share folders
        # with the net usershare command.

        # Maximum number of usershare. 0 (default) means that usershare is disabled.
        ;   usershare max shares = 100

        # Allow users who've been granted usershare privileges to create
        # public shares, not just authenticated ones
           usershare allow guests = yes

        #======================= Share Definitions =======================

        # Un-comment the following (and tweak the other settings below to suit)
        # to enable the default home directory shares. This will share each
        # user's home directory as \\server\username
        ;[homes]
        ;   comment = Home Directories
        ;   browseable = no

        # By default, the home directories are exported read-only. Change the
        # next parameter to 'no' if you want to be able to write to them.
        ;   read only = yes

        # File creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
        # create files with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
        ;   create mask = 0700

        # Directory creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
        # create dirs. with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
        ;   directory mask = 0700

        # By default, \\server\username shares can be connected to by anyone
        # with access to the samba server.
        # Un-comment the following parameter to make sure that only "username"
        # can connect to \\server\username
        # This might need tweaking when using external authentication schemes
        ;   valid users = %S

        # Un-comment the following and create the netlogon directory for Domain Logons
        # (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
        ;[netlogon]
        ;   comment = Network Logon Service
        ;   path = /home/samba/netlogon
        ;   guest ok = yes
        ;   read only = yes

        # Un-comment the following and create the profiles directory to store
        # users profiles (see the "logon path" option above)
        # (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
        # The path below should be writable by all users so that their
        # profile directory may be created the first time they log on
        ;[profiles]
        ;   comment = Users profiles
        ;   path = /home/samba/profiles
        ;   guest ok = no
        ;   browseable = no
        ;   create mask = 0600
        ;   directory mask = 0700

        [printers]
           comment = All Printers
           browseable = no
           path = /var/spool/samba
           printable = yes
           guest ok = no
           read only = yes
           create mask = 0700

        # Windows clients look for this share name as a source of downloadable
        # printer drivers
        [print$]
           comment = Printer Drivers
           path = /var/lib/samba/printers
           browseable = yes
           read only = yes
           guest ok = no
        # Uncomment to allow remote administration of Windows print drivers.
        # You may need to replace 'lpadmin' with the name of the group your
        # admin users are members of.
        # Please note that you also need to set appropriate Unix permissions
        # to the drivers directory for these users to have write rights in it
        ;   write list = root, @lpadmin


        root@kali:~# testparm -s
        Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
        Loaded services file OK.
        Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

        # Global parameters
        [global]
            log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
            logging = file
            map to guest = Bad User
            max log size = 1000
            obey pam restrictions = Yes
            pam password change = Yes
            panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
            passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
            passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
            server role = standalone server
            unix password sync = Yes
            usershare allow guests = Yes
            idmap config * : backend = tdb


        [homes]
            browseable = No
            comment = Home Directories
            create mask = 0700
            directory mask = 0700
            valid users = %S


        [printers]
            browseable = No
            comment = All Printers
            create mask = 0700
            path = /var/spool/samba
            printable = Yes


        [print$]
            comment = Printer Drivers
            path = /var/lib/samba/printers


        [kali]
            comment = Users profiles
            create mask = 0600
            directory mask = 0700
            path = /root/
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Instead of posting your smb.conf (you only need the one on the running Samba server), can you post the results of `testparm -s`?

Comment: The problem is Ubuntu cannot connect in Kali Linux with samba